# Insert foreign key error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

This is my situation : I have two table, tickets and lines and lines belongs to tickets.

I have lot's of row to insert so i'm using the activerecord-import gem.

I create a new Ticket for each row :

```
  t = Ticket.new(store: s)
  t.version             = ticket_thrift.attr.version.to_i
  t.uid                 = ticket_thrift.attr.uid
```

and a lines :

```
 line = Line.new(ticket: t)
```

I'm adding every newest in two array :

```
  @@list_tickets << t
  @@list_lines   << lines
```

And then when i have 20000 i'm trying to insert :

```
 if(@@list_tickets.count == 20000)
  Receipt.import @@list_tickets
  Lines.import   @@list_lines
 end
```

But i have an error because all attributes seems to have nil as value. 
Have you an idea to support foreign key with this gem ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that  the activerecord-import gem cannot not let you make cascade insert.
In the table lines i made a foreign key reference to ticket but the ticket wasn't created in the database yet so the field id_ticket in the table lines was nil.

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign ids to objects:

```
t.version             = ticket_thrift.attr.version.to_i
```

You should do:

```
t.version             = ticket_thrift.attr.version
```

For your model, you should first create the Ticket and then the lines, then associate the line with the tickets:

```
ticket = Ticket.new(params)
ticket.save!
line = Line.new(params)
line.ticket = ticket
line.save!
```

The same applies for your other relations.

Also take a look at the [documentation about associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: the version attribute is an intern id, so it isn't important for my problem. Lines is already associate with the ticket. The problem is that when i'm using the activerecord-import gem : i create the new ticket and the new line first, and in the new line the ticket ( t ) is nil because it hasn't been created in the database yet ..

Comment: @Spierki you need to save your ticket first, to get the id from the database.

Comment: Yes i think it's the issue but i have an other idea, do you know how i can put a foreign key to a field that i choose ? For example, currently, lines referees to ticket_id, can i make lines referees to ticket_uid ?

Comment: @Spierki check this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys